# How to set a time range for one day and transpose it with a certain number

Tags: date-and-time

I would like to create a time list for one day with range from 0:00 to 23:50 and transpose this list with a constant number 239 and then transpose these two lists. 
I tried to make it but it doesn't work:

```
timeList=Range[TimeObject[00,00,00],TimeObject[23,50,00],TimeObject[00,10,00]]
constantList=ConstantArray[239,Length[timeList]]
res=Transpose[{timeList,constantList}]
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with the code in the question: The first, as the error message tells us, is a problem with the syntax for [`TimeObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeObject.html): It should be `TimeObject[{h,m,s}]`, not `TimeObject[h,m,s]` (note the additional list around the arguments). The second issue is that `TimeObject[…]` is not a valid increment, for the same reason as you can't add two `TimeObject`s:

```
TimeObject[{00, 00, 00}] + TimeObject[{00, 10, 00}]
(* TimeObject[{0, 0, 0.}] + TimeObject[{0, 10, 0.}] *)
```

(It simply does not really make sense to say "add the time 13:00 to the time 11:00")

What we *can* do is add a quantity, e.g. `Quantity[10, "min"]`:

```
timeList = Range[TimeObject[{00, 00, 00}], TimeObject[{23, 50, 00}], Quantity[10, "min"]];
constantList = ConstantArray[239, Length[timeList]];
res = Transpose[{timeList, constantList}]
(* long output… *)
```